# Convert Gsons JsonNull object into an enum

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I have to work with an API which returns the following.

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "data": {       
        "mfa": null
    }
}
```

The `mfa` can either be true, false or null. Null is the returned value when the mfa status is unknown.
So I thought it would be nice to model this with an enum, and if the response is null have an unknown state represent it, like the following:

```
@JsonAdapter (MFAAdapter.class)
public enum MFA {
    UNKNOWN,
    USED,
    NOT_USED
}
```

I have also wrote an adapter to handle the conversion.

```
public class MFAAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<MFA> {

    @Override
    public MFA deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext
        jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {
        if (jsonElement.isJsonNull()) {
            return MFA.UNKNOWN;
        } else {
            return jsonElement.getAsBoolean() ? MFA.USED : MFA.NOT_USED;
        }
    }
}
```

However, it seems like my deserialize implementation never gets called, I have tried to debug it but didn't hit the breakpoint.
If the response contains `true` or `false` value for the `mfa` field, it is deserialized into the proper enum representation.

Is my approach correct to this problem? If so, what am I missing here?

Comment: Looks like you need to register the deserializer in the mapper.  Maybe this will help: 
 https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it is implemented this way, so the custom deserializing logic will not be called:

```
@Override public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    if (deserializer == null) {
      return delegate().read(in);
    }
    JsonElement value = Streams.parse(in);
    if (value.isJsonNull()) {
      return null;
    }
    return deserializer.deserialize(value, typeToken.getType(), context);
  }
```